# Parse error: syntax error, (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to access the website which is on subdomain, it was working fine and now it's giving me the

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'all' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /home/customer/www/dev.recycletechnologies.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 457

I checked the code and everything seems to be fine for me. I don't understand why it's giving me this error. The code is pasted below - please help me to find the bug. This code is from line 450 to 460.

```php
     // Do 'all' actions first.
    if ( isset( $wp_filter['all'] ) ) {
        $wp_current_filter[] = $hook_name;
        $all_args            = func_get_args(); // phpcs:ignore
  PHPCompatibility.FunctionUse.ArgumentFunctionsReportCurrentValue.NeedsInspection
        _wp_call_all_hook( $all_args );
    }
           
    if ( ! isset( $wp_filter[ $hook_name ] ) ) {
        if ( isset( $wp_filter['all'] ) ) {
            array_pop( $wp_current_filter );
        }
```

Comment: `PHPCompatibility.FunctionUse.ArgumentFunctionsReportCurrentValue.NeedsInspection` just isn't valid code at all as far as I can see. Aside from that there are no other syntax errors in this block.

Comment: In the original this should be on one line, https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/plugin.php#L491 (slightly different line number there, but that is probably due to which WP version you are actually running)